# Playing mpeg2ts with Gstreamer-1.0

Tags: gstreamer, embedded-linux, multimedia, mpeg2-ts, mpeg-2

I am trying to play a .ts file with Gstreamer-1.0 as well as gst-omx have been successfully installed .
Try to play ts video using below command line format but failed to play.

```
test@test-Gardenia:~/Videos$ gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location= mpeg2.ts ! tsdemux  !  mpegvideoparse ! omxmpeg2dec ! videoconvert ! ximagesink
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTSDemux:tsdemux0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
mpegtsbase.c(1347): mpegts_base_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTSDemux:tsdemux0:
stream stopped, reason not-linked
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTSDemux:tsdemux0.GstPad:audio_0044: caps = "NULL"
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Tried below command also but not did not work.

```
test@test:~/Videos$ gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location= mpeg2.ts ! tsdemux ! tsparse ! omxmpeg2dec ! videoconvert ! ximagesink
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not link mpegtsparse2-0 to omxmpeg2videodec-omxmpeg2dec0
```

Can any one help me how to play .ts file with mpeg2 codec format using gstreamer

Comment: This pipe works for me.. maybe the problem is in ts file `filesrc location= football.ts ! tsdemux  !  mpegvideoparse ! avdec_mpeg2video ! videoconvert ! ximagesink` .. or in omx

Comment: seems to be problem with the audio content of the file

Comment: you can answer your own question or close it .. but better to answer it yourself..